# Can't get elasticsearch to run as a service on Ubuntu 12.0.4 (Natty) - ElasticSearch may have failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04

I've read three of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815392/unable-to-run-elasticsearch-as-a-service-on-ubuntu) and [here](https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278063/installing-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-12-04). Followed those three however it doesn't work. Whenever I tried running elasticsearch as a service:

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

it always gives me:

```
Waiting for ElasticSearch................................
WARNING: ElasticSearch may have failed to start.
```

Now when I try to find the error log (/var/log/elasticsearch), it's never there. ANy idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have the JDK and you have specified the `JAVA_HOME` and the `ES_HOME` vars.

The following snippet works for me:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk # if you haven't
sudo export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 >> /etc/bash.bashrc
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.6.tar.gz
tar xvf elasticsearch-0.90.6.tar.gz
mv elasticsearch-0.90.6 elasticsearch
cd elasticsearch
sudo export ES_HOME=`(pwd)` >> /etc/bash.bashrc
cd ./bin
./elasticsearch -f  # to run in the foreground
```

Whenever you want, you can type the following, in order to see what the program do:

`tail -f ES_HOME/logs/elasticsearch.log`

Finally, you can kill the program with the pid. There are a lot of ways. A simple is the following:

```
ps -ef |grep elasticsearch
kill #PID result of previous command
```

of more easy:

```
pkill -f elasticsearch
```

Comment: i canrun it as a foreground job just fine but cant get it to run as a service

Comment: if you run in the background then the logs go to `ES_HOME/logs/elasticsearch.log`. There, maybe you found something usefull as a java exception.

Comment: running in the background job is as simple as not using the -f option right?

Comment: how do I know if it's running and how do I stop it?

Comment: Run `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch status`

Answer (score 0):

Configure the elastic search in ubuntu.
Please check here for the proper guidance.

> [Installing ElasticSearch on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278063/installing-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-12-04/35874166#35874166)