# Elasticsearch may have failed to start..tried multiple versions

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, jvm, elasticsearch, wrapper

I am keep getting above error ..
I need to setup elasticsearch on my local machine

I followed  github & original website both with `0.20.2` & `0.19.2` version but still have the same issue. I also tried to `set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE` to `1024` ,`512`,`256` but no luck

```
cd ~

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless -y

# Download the compiled elasticsearch rather than the source.
wget http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.2.tar.gz -O elasticsearch.tar.gz
tar -xf elasticsearch.tar.gz
rm elasticsearch.tar.gz
sudo mv elasticsearch-* elasticsearch
sudo mv elasticsearch /usr/local/share

curl -L http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper/tarball/master | tar -xz
sudo mv *servicewrapper*/service /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/
rm -Rf *servicewrapper*
sudo /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch install
sudo ln -s `readlink -f /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch` /usr/local/bin/rcelasticsearch

sudo service elasticsearch start
```

my wrapper.log says

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/02/12 15:28:26 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 15:28:27 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2014/02/12 15:28:32 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 15:28:34 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 15:28:38 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/02/12 15:28:38 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2014/02/12 15:28:39 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticsearchF
```

my **elasticsearch.conf** is as

```
set.default.ES_HOME=<Path to Elasticsearch Home>

set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE=512

wrapper.startup.timeout=300

wrapper.shutdown.timeout=300

wrapper.ping.timeout=300

wrapper.java.command=java

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

wrapper.working.dir=%ES_HOME%

wrapper.java.classpath.1=%ES_HOME%/bin/service/lib/wrapper.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.2=%ES_HOME%/lib/elasticsearch*.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.3=%ES_HOME%/lib/*.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.4=%ES_HOME%/lib/sigar/*.jar
```

Comment: found this but still need better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862480/cant-get-elasticsearch-to-run-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-12-0-4-natty-elasticse

Comment: Try this, it works fine for me https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Elasticsearch Service Wrapper installation instructions](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper):

> Important: If you want to use service wrapper with elasticsearch 0.90 (and below), you need to switch to the 0.90 branch of this repository and then follow the installation instructions.

Looks like the master branch of the Elasticsearch Service Wrapper has been updated to address some class renaming that happened in the Elasticsearch 1.0.0-RC1 release ([issue #4634](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4634)). Please try using the 0.90 branch version of Elasticsearch wrapper, that should resolve your issue.